# Which is to use Stop/Start timer vs SynchronizingObject vs lock for System.Timers.Timer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.timers.timer

*Top note: Per comments I could guess all are working solutions [with this note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163541/which-is-to-use-stop-start-timer-vs-synchronizingobject-vs-lock-for-system-timer#comment81276951_47163541) Indeed in my application I am trying to combine them. By the way before downvoting you could ask me for details.*

*Top note 2: By the way, as SO is different from MSO downvotes or close votes encourages deleting question, I won't, otherwise all valuable comments and answer will be deleted. Here is a place to help and try to understand each other*

Here is most basic of 4 different implemantations of linqpad codes. Except first all others gives desired output.

Can you explain details for them?

As I have many timers in my application I need to manage and synchronize, in complete code which is to best use and what are the pro/cons of alternative solutions

Without  Neither SynchronizingObject nor timer stop/start nor lock

```
System.Timers.Timer timer2 = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
int i = 0;
void Main()
{
    timer2.Elapsed += PromptForSave;
    timer2.Start();
}

private void PromptForSave(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    i = i + 1;
    Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(100, 1000));
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Gives:

> 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 15 15 17 18 20 21 22

---

With SynchronizingObject:

```
void Main()
{
    timer2.Elapsed += PromptForSave;
    timer2.SynchronizingObject = new Synchronizer();
    timer2.Start();
}

private void PromptForSave(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    i = i + 1;
    Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(100, 1000));
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

---

With timer Start/Stop

```
void Main()
{
    timer2.Elapsed += PromptForSave;    
    timer2.Start();
}

private void PromptForSave(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer2.Stop();
    i = i + 1;
    Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(100, 1000));
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    timer2.Start();
}
```

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

---

finally with lock

```
object lockForTimer = new object();
void Main()
{
    timer2.Elapsed += PromptForSave;    
    timer2.Start();
}

private void PromptForSave(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock(lockForTimer){
        i = i + 1;
        Thread.Sleep(new Random().Next(100, 1000));
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        timer2.Start();
    }
}
```

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

Syncronizer looks like:

```
public class Synchronizer : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    private Thread m_Thread;
    private BlockingCollection<Message> m_Queue = new BlockingCollection<Message>();

    public Synchronizer()
    {
        m_Thread = new Thread(Run);
        m_Thread.IsBackground = true;
        m_Thread.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Message message = m_Queue.Take();
            message.Return = message.Method.DynamicInvoke(message.Args);
            message.Finished.Set();
        }
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.Method = method;
        message.Args = args;
        m_Queue.Add(message);
        return message;
    }

    public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Message message = result as Message;
        if (message != null)
        {
            message.Finished.WaitOne();
            return message.Return;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("result");
    }

    public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.Method = method;
        message.Args = args;
        m_Queue.Add(message);
        message.Finished.WaitOne();
        return message.Return;
    }

    public bool InvokeRequired
    {
        get { return Thread.CurrentThread != m_Thread; }
    }

    private class Message : IAsyncResult
    {
        public Delegate Method = null;
        public object[] Args = null;
        public object Return = null;
        public object State = null;
        public ManualResetEvent Finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public object AsyncState
        {
            get { return State; }
        }

        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
        {
            get { return Finished; }
        }

        public bool CompletedSynchronously
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return Finished.WaitOne(0); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this useful (and what is the actual question).  It seems like you're asking for opinions which are not on-topic for SO.

Comment: We can't choose for you between working solutions, knowing nothing about your application's needs. If you have performance requirements, whether of time, memory or contention, profile. Otherwise, prefer the simplest solution you understand, and have an interface that allows you to easily switch out approaches if you foresee the need to change.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't understand differences between them, that I ask

Comment: `lock`ing is dangerous in this case, it may blow up your thread pool. The other two solutions will work, the choice depends on the particular use case.

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks for helpfult and constructive comment

Comment: There's a dedicated SE site for code review, by the way (codereview.stackexchange.com), which this seems to be a great example of.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is a dangerous class.  I think it got added to the framework after a usability study showed that programmer test subjects failed miserably in using System.Threading.Timer.  That it swallows all exceptions without a peep is nasty, giving its AutoReset property a default of *true* is vile.  And is what produces these outcomes, you have a bad firehose problem where the timer ticks faster than your code allows.  This does not bomb your program quickly enough, nobody spends that much time in a debugging session.  But does in production, with a memory leak that is hard to see.

Comment: Proper advice is to ensure that AutoReset is set to *false*.  Only ever allow *true* when the Interval is at least an order of magnitude longer than the maximum amount of time needed by the Elapsed event handler.  If you are not sure how long it might take, or assume it might get worse over time because of, say, a dbase filling up, then always set it to *false*.

Comment: @HansPassant Then you suggest System.Threading.Timer instead? I am a bit miserable about timers, already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47120678/492258)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The 4th solution (`lock`) is a dangerous one. Since the `Elapsed` event will be raised on a `ThreadPool` thread each time and you might potentially block many of them simultaneously, this could cause the `ThreadPool` to grow (with all the consequences). So that solution is a bad one.
- The 3rd solution (start/stop) will process the events not at the rate set by the timer, but rather at the rate that depends on how much time does each particular action take. So it may "skip" many events. This solution is like a "frame drop" in video streaming.
- The 2nd solution will enqueue all the actions and won't skip them. It's potentially dangerous when the action's processing time is (almost always) longer than the timer interval. The queue will only grow causing an `OutOfMemoryException` at some time. This solution is like a "frame buffer" in video streaming.
- The 1st one should be deleted, there are only issues with that.

So you should choose between the 2nd and the 3rd solution depending on what is of importance for your use case: a reliable processing of all incoming events or a processing with a maximal possible throughput (rate).

Comment: They are all dangerously wrong the same way, the threadpool queue will always get overwhelmed.  The lock just makes it crash quicker on OOM, like two weeks instead of four.  Makes it better :)  Pretty hard to debug either way.

Comment: @HansPassant, what's the problem with the third one? I see only the absence of `AutoReset = false`.

Comment: Okay, not as bad, but it is a race.  If other code is using the threadpool as well then Elapsed is going to be delayed.  And the timer won't stop soon enough.